# Get a value from nodejs application into another nodejs application's client-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, dom

So what I am trying to do is a bit unusual but I have no other way of getting a specific object. Let's say I have an app running on http://localhost:3000/ and this app embeds another one running on http://localhost:4000/. Inside the second app, I have a nodejs server which renders one index.html file on which I have several styles/scripts attached to. I need to take a value (perhaps using a request) from http://localhost:3000/ and use it in the script file of http://localhost:4000/. So it is like passing a value from nodejs to the DOM somehow. Has anyone achieved something like this before ?

Comment: Another option is pass a value via URL query (or hash) upon the 2nd app embedding

Comment: How can I add additional url query params on top of existing ones using some library then ?

Comment: It depends on how you embed the 2nd app into the 1st one.